# Prove the sequence $\{1/n!\}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Here is what I have so far:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given
We want for all $n >N$,  $|1/n! - 0|< \varepsilon$

We know $1/n <ε$ and $1/n! ≤ 1/n < ε$.
I don't know how to solve for $n$, given $1/n!$. And this is where I get stuck in my proof, I cannot solve for $n$, and therefore cannot pick $N > \cdots$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$1/n<\varepsilon$"? What is $\varepsilon$? What is $n$?

Comment: I have previously proven that {1/n} converges to 0. And to do this I used |1/n -0| < ε hence, 1/n < ε, and n> 1/ε. I am trying to use this fact to solve for n in 1/n! <ε

Comment: Careful, you're trying to show |1/n - 0| < ε to show 1/n converges to 0. it isn't given to you, which is sort of what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have previously proven it in my problem so I'm using that fact as a given to help me solve this problem with 1/n!

Comment: @Suzanna: But you already *found* such an $n$.... All you need is that $n>\frac1\varepsilon,$ and then you'll have $$\frac1{n!}\le\frac1n<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Three answers have appeared but I am the only person who has up-voted the question. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0 < \frac{1}{n!} < \frac{1}{n}$, by the squeeze theorem...

Without squeeze theorem: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Define $N = \epsilon^{-1}$. Then if $n > N$, $$\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right| = \frac{1}{n!} < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} = \epsilon$$

Comment: I have to prove it using ε, N not through the squeeze theorem

Comment: @Suzanna I have modified it to add another solution

Comment: @Suzanna: "squeeze theorem" is just a fancy name for "for every $\varepsilon$, the $N$ that works for one of the sequences also works (unchanged) for the other".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *solve for* $n$, just to find *some* $n$ that is large enough that $1/n!$ is smaller than $\varepsilon$. It doesn't matter if you find an $N$ that is much larger than it *needs to be*, as long as it is finite.

By the hint that $1/n! \le 1/n$, therefore, it is enough to find an $N$ that is large enough that $1/n < \varepsilon$. And this is clearly the case if only $n > 1/\varepsilon$ ...

Comment: Did you mean to say it is enough to find an N that is large enough that 1/n!<ε....

Comment: @Suzanna: No, I meant exactly what I wrote. If you find an $N$ that is large enough that $1/n<\varepsilon$, it will _automatically also_ be large enough that $1/n!<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:  $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=e^1=e.$$ Thus the series converges and therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n!}=0.$$